# Kotlin Assignment Expressions in Conditionals

Tags: kotlin

Does Kotlin have anything similar to Python code below?

```py
foo = ["a", "b", "c"]
if (bar:=len(foo)) > 1: print(f"List size: {bar}")
```

```
List size: 3
```

Where bar is assigned a value of foo within the conditional.

Comment: Kotlin doesn't support defining variables inside conditions. Also assignments are not expressions, they don't return anything. So this would not be possible

Answer (score 2):

No, but instead Kotlin has some useful [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html)

In Kotlin you would write the equivalent like this:

```kotlin
    val foo = arrayOf("a","b","c")
    foo.size.takeIf{ it > 1 }?.also{ println("List size: $it") }
```

One would find Kotlin fun and beautiful when they end up writing a long chain of dots getting to the goal in a straight line, without needing to declare a bunch of variables or go back to wrap the whole thing with a function or brackets.